# spinner dropdowns ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android

i need spinner that drop downs an **ExpandableListView**.please help me to do that.Actually when we click Spinner Drop down of List View Will come.instead of List View I need **ExpandableListView** please check my image also.[image]

Comment: Your question lacks any explanation of what you've already done to solve your problem and what is blocking you.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly use an ExpandableListView for the Spinner popup, any more than you can directly use a ListView for the Spinner popup. It is what it is, and that is defined by the Spinner class.

Options include:

- Subclassing Spinner and overriding whatever drives the popup dialog
- Copying Spinner into your project and replacing whatever drives the popup dialog (if overriding will not work due to method visibility, etc.)
- Don't use a Spinner, and instead use a Button plus an AlertDialog containing an ExpandableListView, or something like that

In principle, you could override getDropDownView() in your SpinnerAdapter (e.g., ArrayAdapter). However, there is no concept of the drop-down view being disabled, and I assume you would want your category headers to be non-selectable. If, however, selecting a category is acceptable, this approach would be simplest.